# An alternating sum with binomial coefficients is not a prime number

Tags: prime-numbers, binomial-theorem

Suppose $n\geq 5$ is an odd positive integer. Prove that $${n \choose 1}-5{n \choose 2}+5^2{n \choose 3}-...+5^{n-1}{n\choose n}$$ is not a prime number.

I tried expanding each to see if anything jumped out at me to prove this. I am struggling. Any help or hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: **Hint:** Expand $(5-1)^n$ using the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: Thank you! This helped, it finally clicked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Let
\begin{align}
\phi_{n} = {n \choose 1}-5{n \choose 2}+5^2{n \choose 3}-...+5^{n-1}{n\choose n}
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
-5 \phi_{n} &= \sum_{r=1}^{n} \binom{n}{r} (-5)^{r} = -1 + \sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} (-5)^{r} \\
&= (1-5)^{n} -1
\end{align} 
or
\begin{align}
\phi_{n} = \frac{ 1 -(-4)^{n} }{ 5 }.
\end{align}
For the case of $n=5$ the result is $\phi_{5} = 205 = 5 \cdot 41$ which is the product of two primes. Further results show that $\phi_{n \geq 5}$ is not prime.